# 'echo' eats part of the message

Tags: bash, echo

I want to write a script that will dump all partitions of my android device through the android debug bridge and since this is a time intensive process I want to notify the user about the progress by echoing out messages after certain key events happen. To my surprise I have noticed that sometimes `echo` does not print all the characters that it should.

The smallest sample that reproduces the error is:

```
#!/bin/bash

targets=$(adb shell "ls /dev/block/nand*")

for item in $targets; do
    echo "Processing $item"
    echo "dd if=$item bs=4M"
done
```

This produces the following output:

```
Processing /dev/block/nanda
dd if=/dev/block/nanda bs=4M
Processing /dev/block/nandd
dd if=/dev/block/nandd bs=4M
Processing /dev/block/nandg
dd if=/dev/block/nandg bs=4M
Processing /dev/block/nandj
 bs=4M/dev/block/nandj
Processing /dev/block/nandb
dd if=/dev/block/nandb bs=4M
Processing /dev/block/nande
dd if=/dev/block/nande bs=4M
Processing /dev/block/nandh
 bs=4M/dev/block/nandh
Processing /dev/block/nandc
dd if=/dev/block/nandc bs=4M
Processing /dev/block/nandf
dd if=/dev/block/nandf bs=4M
Processing /dev/block/nandi
 bs=4M/dev/block/nandi
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `$item` ends with a carriage return, so the cursor zips back to the beginning of the line and prints `<space>bs=4M`

You can do `item=${item%$'\r'}`